# Does the assembler perform the same tasks as the translator from C to assembly?

Tags: compiler, optimization, assembly

When compiling C programs to assembly programs and then to machine programs, does the assembler (e.g. the one used in GCC or other popular C compilers) perform the same tasks as the translator from C to assembly, i.e.

- parsing
- code generation
- optimization?

How much is the amount of optimization done by the assembler compared to the amount of optimization done by the translator from C to assembly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, on a high level there is some similarity. It's just that translating from assembly to machine code is much much simpler than translating C code to assembly. It is better to understand the assembler as a macro expansion engine that replaces mnemonics for instructions with their binary machine code. As such, assemblers don't perform any optimization, unless you count that one mnemonic could expand to different instructions depending on operands and configuration.

In reality things are slightly more complicated. E.g. an assembler has to perform a second pass to fix up jump targets. And if we look at some compilers like LLVM, a lot of optimizations happen with an Intermediate Representation (IR) that can be directly converted to and from an assembly-like text format. Compilers don't generally emit assembly code but use code generation backends that typically generate machine code directly. Also, optional link-time optimization (LTO) occurs after compiling individual compilation units or modules. While LTO conceptually operates on machine code (object files), in practice the compiler will have saved the IR in the object file, so that the static linker will generate the final machine code.

Answer (score 3):

> When compiling C programs to assembly programs and then to machine programs, does the assembler (e.g. the one used in GCC or other popular C compilers) perform the same tasks as the translator from C to assembly, i.e.
>
> - parsing
> - code generation
> - optimization?

It really depends on what you mean by "the same tasks". Generally speaking, asking about the difference between a compiler and an assembler doesn't make much sense, mainly because an assembler *is* a compiler.

A compiler is a program that translates a program written in language A into a semantically equivalent program written in language B. An assembler translates from assembly to machine code, therefore it is a compiler.

But not every compiler is an assembler. Basically, we have specific names for specific kinds of compilers depending on the (perceived) levels of abstraction of languages A and B, the operations the compiler performs the time when the compiler runs, and sometimes even the community.

For example, when A has a lower (perceived) level of abstraction than B, then we call the compiler a *decompiler* (except when A is machine language and B is assembly, then we call it a *disassembler*), when A and B have the same perceived level of abstraction, then we call it a *source-to-source translator* or *transpiler* if the perceived level of abstraction is high and a *binary translator* if the perceived level is low. When the compiler runs before the code is executed, we call it an *ahead-of-time* compiler, when the compiler runs while the code is executed, we call it a *just-in-time* compiler. And so on and so forth.

In real-world compilers, the compiler not only produces an output program, but it also produces error messages and warnings. If it *only* produces error messages and warnings and doesn't actually produce an output program, then we might call it a *linter*, a *static analyzer*, or a *semantic analyzer* depending on the sophistication of its analysis and the class of things it is looking for (e.g. potential security bugs vs. violations of coding style). If A = B, but the output program is re-formatted according to some rules, we call it a *pretty-printer*. If A = B but the output program is in some sense more efficient, we might call it an *optimizer*.

If A = B and the output program is optimized for source code size, we call it a *minifier*. If A = B and the output program is made to be hard to understand, we call it an *obfuscator*.

If B = A + formatting annotations (e.g. color, size, font, etc.) we would call it a *lexical highlighter*, *syntax highlighter*, or *semantic highlighter*, depending on which level it operates at.

As you can see, there are *many* "subtypes" of the general type "compiler", and all have their own specialized name.

So, what *is* an assembler, then?

An Assembler is a compiler, where the output language B is machine language for *some* sort of machine (it could be JVM byte code for the Java Virtual Machine, for example) and the input language A is a human-readable textual language that has a simple 1:1 mapping to the output language B. We often talk about assembly language being composed of *mnemonics*, which are simply names for the bit patterns that make up the machine language.

Most assemblers have *some* simple abstraction features that go beyond just providing a simple 1:1 mapping of mnemonics to opcodes, such as constants, symbolic names for registers, simple local variables (essentially having the assembler assign registers by itself), simplification of the command set (e.g. if the CPU ISA has two separate opcodes for adding floats and ints, the assembler may have only a single mnemonic and emit the correct opcode based on whether you passed FP registers or GP registers as operands), synthetic mnemonics (e.g. MIPS doesn't have an opcode for loading a constant, instead you use the `ORI` (OR with immediate value) opcode with the zero register (a synthetic register which always contains `0`), but many MIPS assemblers have an `LDI <constant>` mnemonic that simply translates to `ORI r0, <constant>`), includes, macros, etc.

The boundary where a sophisticated powerful expressive macro-assembler's input language stops being "high-level assembly" and starts being a "low-level programming language" are fluid and depending on context and opinion.

> How much is the amount of optimization done by the assembler compared to the amount of optimization done by the translator from C to assembly?

Generally, none at all. This would be one of the cases where the above-mentioned boundary is passed. If there is any (significant) amount of optimization being done, we would simply no longer call it an assembler.

So, an assembler needs to do lexical and syntactical analysis (i.e. lexing and parsing), but it does not do sophisticated semantic analysis. It does to code generation (obviously), but it does not need to perform a complex semantic mapping between the input and output languages (unlike e.g. a compiler that compiles from C to ECMAScript or from Haskell to AMD64 machine code), instead there is a simple 1:1 correspondence between mnemonics and opcodes with the occasional synthetic mnemonic or macro substitution. There is typically no optimization.

Answer (score 2):

An assembler has to do lexical analysis and parsing, but then will do the translation as literal as possible. No optimisation. Nothing.

The best you can expect is the assembler picking the shorter of alternative instructions, or using alternative spellings for instructions.

Comment: Assemblers also typically do backpatching, and similar processes happen in compilers too.